# gamma mixed model with offset and/or weights?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, weights, offset

I have some continuous positive data $Y_{ij}$ representing accumulated quantities, where $i$ denotes subject and $j$ a state. Patients are transitioning across states sequentially, but not all patients visit all states. Also, the assumption here is that $Y_{ij}$ were accumulated at a **constant** rate within each state $j$, but these rates are different across states. We have the times $t_{ij}$ where subjects spent in each state. We also have some other covariates, some time dependent, some not. The interest here is to estimate the **mean rate** conditional on state, as well as on values of the other covariates. This is different from estimating the mean $Y$ conditional on time, state and covariates.

I was thinking of fitting a generalized linear mixed model, with the following characteristics:

- time values $t_{ij}$ can be used as offset, so that rate can be estimated
- the model will be of the Gamma family with log link, for convenience
  for the offset (log of times will be used)
- the correlation between
  $Y_{ij}$ across $j$ values within $i$ will be expressed with one random
  effect expressing the random intercept per subject i
- states will be
  categorical variable (choosing one of them as baseline)

What I am not
sure about is if I also need to use time as weights. I want to model
the fact that $Y_{ij}$ for longer times should have higher “weight”,
since the “rate” is estimated over a longer period of accumulation.

I was thinking of using `glmer` function in `lme4` R package.

Any comment/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you estimate the *amount* rather than the rate.

If you really think that patients are accumulating "stuff" linearly with time during their stay in each state, then you should use an offset of $\log(t_{ij})$ in conjunction with a log link for the Gamma model (I usually recommend this in any case). Suppose the model is parameterized with an intercept $\beta_1$, $\beta_{2} \ldots \beta_{n}$ for the effects of being in a state other than the first, and $\beta_{n+1} \ldots \beta_{n+k}$ for the effects of $k$ other covariates. Then if an individual is in the $j$th state ($j>1$),

Then the expression

$$
\eta_0 = \beta_1 + \beta_{j} + \sum_m \beta_{m+n} x_m
$$

defines the *linear predictor*, i.e. the logarithm of the predicted rate at which "stuff" is accumulated for that individual. But we add the offset to this baseline linear predictor: $\eta=\eta_0+\log(t)$, so that the predicted amount of stuff is $\exp(\eta) = \exp(\eta_0) \cdot t = \textrm{predicted rate} \cdot t$.

If you add $\log(t)$ as an additional predictor rather than an offset, then you'll estimate one more parameter $\beta_{n+k+1}$, and your model will become $\exp(\eta_0 + \beta_{n+k+1} \log(t)) = \exp(\eta_0) t^{\beta_{n+k+1}}$, which will allow you to model non-linear accumulation (if $\beta_{n+k+1}<1$, stuff is accumulating slower than linearly/decelerating; if $\beta_{n+k+1}>1$, stuff is accumulating faster than linearly/accelerating)

Comment: Thanks Ben, this is how of I thought of it exactly. I am glad you had similar thoughts. One thing I am not sure how to do (and if I have to) is to "weight" more observations with larger $t_{ij}$, since they would be more informative in the estimation of the rate. I remember reading that in a Poisson model, using time as offset or weight give the same analysis. But I am not sure if I need to explicitly use weights in the case of the gamma mixed model with offset.