# Offset vs weigths in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, weights, offset

I was wondering from a technical perspective what approach I should follow in this modelling problem I have.
I have a target variable `Y` which is a continuous random variable defined in the interval [0; infinity). For this reason (and this is also verified by the data itself) I decided to use a tweedie distribution. Moreover, I would like to have a multiplicative model, so I am using a log link-function.
I also know that the variable `Y` is linearly dependent on the `time` variable. It is assumed that the more the `time`, the higher the `Y` value is.
Given these conditions I followed two different approaches:

1. Modeling the variable directly and using `time` as a log offset. Following R syntax the model would look like the following `glm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + ... + offset(log(time)), family = tweedie(link = "log"))`
2. Modeling the ratio of `Y` and `time` and using `time` as training weights. Defining `Y_time = Y / time` we have `glm(Y_time ~ X1 + X2 + ..., weights = time, family = tweedie(link = "log"))`

Which approach is more theoretically sound?

Comment: Do some of this old posts help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246318/difference-between-offset-and-weights, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326525/gamma-mixed-model-with-offset-and-or-weights, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297859/can-weights-and-offset-lead-to-similar-results-in-poisson-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358980/can-i-model-incidence-per-1000-people-per-month-using-poisson-regression-without,

Comment: Using log(time) as an offset would not yield a predicted outcome that would b e"linear in time" but would rather yield a model that would be "geometric in time" due to the inverse of the link function being exponential on the original time scale.